# Beginning and end of the month from year and month input excel

Tags: excel, date

I need guidance and help with an Excel question.

I am trying to automate a part of my salary slip.

I want the following , to always display the beginning of the month and end of the month.

"Period:  2018-02-01-2018-02-28"

For instance, if I have two cells in which I feed year: 2018 and month 02 or month 03 then , this should automatically update the : "Period: 2018-02-01-2018-02-28 or 2018-03-01-2018-03-31".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming that you need to do this with formula. If your year is in **A1** and month in **B1**, type the below in **C1**

```
="Period: " & TEXT(DATE(A1,B1,"1"),"yyyy-mm-dd") & " " & TEXT(EOMONTH(DATE(A1,B1,"1"),0), "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Now when you change the month in **B1** (or year in **A1**), **C1** will automatically update itself. Below is a screen shot of how it have it setup:
[image]

Comment: The output is as following: Period: yyyy-00-01 yyyy-00-31 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Which cells hold the year and month? and can you provide what you have typed in your resulting cell?

Comment: ="Period: "&TEXT(DATE(R10C1;R10C2;"1");"YYYY-MM-DD")& " - " &TEXT(EOMONTH(DATE(R10C1;R10C2;"1");0); "YYYY-MM-DD")

Comment: What's **R10C1** and **R10C2**? are these cells you have renamed?

Comment: Those are the cells where year and month place reside. I checked my Excel 2016 options. It is working with R1C1 system. Even if I try to deselect it, it does not go back to A1 system.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but `I checked my Excel 2016 options`? are you not working in excel?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `="Period: "&TEXT((DATE(B2,1,1)),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"-"&TEXT(EOMONTH(DATE(B2,1,1),C2-1),"yyyy-mm-dd")`

[image]